how to pass AAD AccessToken to authenticate SQL Server using aioodbc library?
I'm using aioodbc to connect to Azure SQL Server.
I wanted to pass accessToken to authenticate SQL server instead of admin user/pass.
I see some links that PyOdbc supports passing accessToken when creating connection. Is there similar one for aioodbc as well?

This GitHub comment suggests that aioodbc uses the same connection string as pyodbc.

@GordThompson Pyodbc is passing access token something like this conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string, attrs_before = { SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN:tokenstruct }) , not part of connection string

I have followed this article ( if you wanted to pass accessToken ) - check it out https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/how-to-connect-azure-sql-database-from-python-function-app-using/ba-p/3035595
Create Access Token using msal:
authority = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{APP_TENANT_ID}'
scope = ['https://database.windows.net//.default']    
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(APP_CLIENT_ID, authority=authority, client_credential=client_secret)
            token_response = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
            access_token = token_response.get('access_token')

Convert that access token to be usable inside Pyodbc connect
exptoken = b''
for i in bytes(access_token, "UTF-8"):
    exptoken += bytes({i})
    exptoken += bytes(1)

    tokenstruct = struct.pack("=i", len(exptoken)) + exptoken

    async with aioodbc.connect(dsn=conn_str, attrs_before={ SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN:tokenstruct }) as conn:

